# Which behavior used to change page in dropDownBox

Tags: java, wicket

my droDownBox look like:

```
        add(new DropDownChoice<String>("hladaneSlovo", new HladaneSlova()).add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onchange") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                target.prependJavaScript("window.location.href='" + urlFor(VyjimkyPage.class, null) + "'");

            }

        }));
```

This I have in my base page. There is also some default value. How to change page when I select one of selected option ? Problem with implementation what I created now is in default value. When I selected item which is already selected nothing is doing. What  behavor is call when I select value ?

Comment: What is your desired behaviour? You want to change the page depending on the DDC selection? Can you derive the target page from the selection model? Do you realy need to do this via Ajax? I dont think so.

Comment: I want to change page if I select any item in the dropDownBox. This example doesnt work if I select selected item then I nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the selected value to pass validation and to update your drop down's model, instead of using an *AjaxEventBehavior*, which will not update the model, you should be using the *AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior* (instead of the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior which doesn't work properly with Choices or Groups).

```
DropDownChoice choice = new DropDownChoice("hladaneSlovo", new HladaneSlova());
add(choice);
choice.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior()
{
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
        //The model is now updated so you can push to DB or pass as PageParameter to the next page

        // throw a RedirectException so that the url will be updated for your page
        throw new RedirectException(VyjimkyPage.class); 
    }
});
```

**Note:** part of the problem that you are facing with your implementation is that you are chaining the add() method.  The return value of the add method is a Component, but it is not the Component that you just added, rather the Component that you are adding to.  When adding AjaxEventBehavior's, you should add them to the Component you want to listen for the event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the page there is no need to use AJAX so you can do something like this:

```
DropDownChoice<String> dropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice<String>("hladaneSlovo", new HladaneSlova()) {
        @Override
        protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSelectionChanged(String newSelection) {
            setResponsePage(NewPage.class);
        }
};
```

And in your implementation the value is still default because you need to use `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` behavior if you want to update the model when the javascript event is fire.

Comment: thx but the problem is still same. If there is some value selected and I select I select this value nothing happens

Comment: @jordeu: this is what I was aiming for too. But I have problems understanding hudi.